# setZoomScale breaks ability to scroll in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

One of my apps has a `UIWebView` which loads a particular pdf from the user's device. After the webView has loaded I would like to set the zoom scale and `contentOffset`. However, if the pdf takes a while to load, the user can no longer scroll - they can see the whole pdf and can zoom in/out, but it only zooms into the top-left corner and you can't scroll at all. (You can scroll if you zoom in further than zoom scale).

(For completeness) I run this code in `viewDidAppear`:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filename.pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

The main code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if (!loadFailedBool) {
        [self performSelector:@selector(zoomIntoWebView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
    }
}

- (void)zoomIntoWebView {
    [webView.scrollView  setZoomScale:5.0 animated:NO];
    webView.scrollView .contentOffset = CGPointMake(600, 420);
}
```

I have removed any unnecessary code, but as you can see, it runs the zoom function after a delay of 0.0. In this circumstance, the above bug happens every time. If I set it to something like 0.3 the code works fine, about 90% of the time.

As a temporary fix, I have set the delay to 0.6 but it is far from ideal, especially if a user is on a older device. If this bug happens every time, this feature of the app becomes unusable. If anyone has any suggestions or a similar problem it will be great to find a solution. Knowing when the pdf has finished loading would probably fix it.